# how to set static ip from bash scriptlinux

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to set static IP using bash script what I would to achieve I want to set the same IP to static which is come from DHCP, for example, my eth0 set to DHCP and it picks IP 51.89.84.82 for eth1 it pick 10.0.0.1 I want to set the same IP to static how can I achieve this in centos7.

1 ) find interface name and its ip , subnet mask , gateway.
2 ) loop each interface and set the same ip , subnet and gateway.

Comment: But why? ......

Comment: i need static so every time i run new vm on cloud i would run this script and set static ip.

Comment: You repeated your question, I ask why do you need to set static IP if you already have one from DHCP.

Comment: there are some service running on it and i want to make the ip static so if its reboot or shutdown the routes and ip should never be change.

Comment: It'd better to set up DNS.

Comment: there is no need for dns i set ip static manually what i want to automate it .

Comment: Many new routers require you to set static ip inside the router. All ips are DHCP. My old router had range for DHCP and you then could from system set a static ip from outside the DHCP range.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Google next time.

Here's a comprehensive guide on how to configure a network interface in RHEL/CentOS 7:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/configure-centos-network-settings

In case you're using Network Manager:

```bsh
nmcli device modify <interface_name> ipv4.address <ip_address>
```

In case you're not using NM:

```
ifconfig <interface> <ip_address> netmask <netmask>
```

or

```
ip a add <ip_addr>/<mask> dev <interface>
```

Comment: kindly read the question what i want to achive i know how to set static ip. i am talking about bash script.

Comment: @I'msK what do you mean? Just put this command into a text file and you have a bash script.

Comment: but this can only be done for 1 interface at a time i have to interface eth0 and eth1

Comment: @I'msK The question only mentions one network interface. Please update your question and give the correct and full context.

Comment: @Kusalananda please check i update

Comment: Are you familiar with using for loops in a bash script?