# how to set staitc ip using bash script centos

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

i want to set static IP for my eth0 adapter it is set to DHCP right now and i want to set it to static using bash script the IP should be same which its currently have or it picks from dhcp.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be in the file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: is this related to same question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611128/how-to-set-static-ip-from-bash-scriptlinux ?